# Is there anyway to change the scatter symbol of an existed Bokeh plot?

Tags: python-2.7, bokeh

I was wondering is there anyways that can change

the symbol of an existed Bokeh plot using bokeh build-in functions just

like changing it's color/size or other parameters?

for instance, here is my scatter plot:

```
scatter = plot.scatter(x, y, marker="square")

scatter.glyph.size = 5           #this part works

scatter.marker     = "triangle"  #this part don't
```

changing marker to triangle part will go wrong,

because this scatter object does not have a "marker" parameter.

Because I would like to manipulate the marker symbol in "real time",

I would like to find a way to modify it or just replacing it after the graph has been ploted.

does anyone get any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a different `glyph` to the renderer:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import bokeh.plotting, bokeh.models
bokeh.plotting.output_notebook()

x = np.random.random(10)
y = np.random.random(10)

f = bokeh.plotting.figure()

scatter = f.scatter(x, y, marker="square")

asterisk_glyph = bokeh.models.glyphs.Asterisk(**scatter.glyph.changed_properties_with_values())

scatter.set(glyph=asterisk_glyph)
scatter.glyph.size = 20

bokeh.plotting.show(f)
```

Comment: This problem brothers me for a while, thanks or your solution, it really helps!

Comment: brothered me too.